# Select element with CSS box-shadow animation applied to it resets itself to default option when expanded/clicked

Tags: html, css, forms, css-animations

I've had a user report an error with a select element that has had an animated box-shadow applied to it. I've verified the issue myself on my work Windows computer. Unfortunately I don't have a Windows machine or environment available at home to debug this with.

I have a select element with a pulsating drop shadow glow applied to it. There is a demo link and code below. In Chrome (26) on Windows, the select element does glow, but when the user clicks on the select menu every second (or less) the menu resets its selection to the first option within the select menu. This makes it impossible to scroll and select the correct option. The select menu has 73 options.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this? The same thing happens if I apply the animation to a parent element that contains the select menu.

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/P72u7/1/

CSS:

```
.glow {
    -webkit-animation-name: promptGlow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: promptGlow;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes promptGlow {
    from {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.22);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.44);
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.22);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select class="glow">
    <option value="1" selected="">Abraham Moss</option>
    <option value="2">Altrincham</option>
    <option value="3">Anchorage</option>
    <option value="4">Ashton Moss</option>
    <option value="73">Woodlands Road</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is wrap the `<select>` in a `<div>` then style the `<div>` Something like this should do the trick:

HTML

```
<div class="glow">
    <select>
        <option value="1" selected="">Abraham Moss</option>
        <option value="2">Altrincham</option>
        <option value="3">Anchorage</option>
        <option value="4">Ashton Moss</option>
        <option value="73">Woodlands Road</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.glow {
    width: 180px; /*This will have to adjust to the width of your select*/
    -webkit-animation-name: promptGlow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: promptGlow;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.glow select {
    border: 0px; /*This removes the small white border that Chrome adds by default*/
}
```

See here for a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9DZht/

Comment: Thanks Dryden. I did think of adding the animation to a parent element and quickly tried it with the Chrome developer tools, I believe the issue was still present. I'm not 100% sure though, so tomorrow when I have access to a Windows machine I will check your fiddle and then mark as the answer if it works.

Comment: Sorry Dryden, that jsfiddle still shows the same problem. I'm starting to think it might be a bug in Chrome 26, but I can't update the version on my work machine to test that theory.

Comment: You might be able to download the newest version of Chrome and install it as the portable version. This usually circumvents most machines' administrator privileges...